# How to disable specific Mirror repository?

Tags: raspbian-buster, apt

I'm trying to install updates. But apt always using `ftp.harukasan.org`. This mirror is too slow. I need to change. I checked `/etc/apt/sources.list`, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` there is no configuration is used `ftp.harukasan.org`.

Edit: apt output

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease [25.2 kB]
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages [259 kB]
Get:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages [13.0 MB]

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  point-rpi
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bubblewrap eject xdg-dbus-proxy
The following packages will be upgraded:
  arandr base-files cron dhcpcd5 distro-info-data e2fsprogs file firmware-atheros firmware-brcm80211 firmware-libertas firmware-misc-nonfree
  firmware-realtek freetype2-doc gldriver-test gtk2-engines-pixflat libarchive13 libcom-err2 libext2fs2 libfm-data libfm-extra4 libfm-gtk-data
  libfm-gtk4 libfm-modules libfm4 libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libfribidi0 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libgs9 libgs9-common
  libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmp3lame0 libmtdev1 libncurses6 libncursesw5 libncursesw6 libobrender32v5 libobt2v5 libogg0
  libpam-systemd libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libraw1394-11 libsord-0-0 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1 libss2
  libssl1.1 libsystemd0 libtinfo5 libtinfo6 libudev1 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libxaw7 libxcb-util0 libxdamage1 libxml2 libxmu6 libxmuu1 libxslt1.1
  libxt6 lxpanel lxpanel-data lxplug-bluetooth lxplug-ejecter lxplug-ptbatt lxplug-volume ncurses-base ncurses-bin ncurses-term obconf openbox
  openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server openssl pcmanfm pi-bluetooth piclone pipanel piwiz python-cryptography python-piglow
  python-werkzeug python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal python3-cryptography python3-piglow python3-werkzeug raspberrypi-kernel
  raspberrypi-sys-mods raspberrypi-ui-mods raspi-config raspi-gpio rc-gui rp-prefapps rpcbind rpi-chromium-mods rpi-eeprom rpi-eeprom-images ssh
  sudo systemd systemd-sysv udev wpasupplicant
113 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 177 MB of archives.
After this operation, 3628 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf rpi-chromium-mods armhf 20191118 [9189 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.harukasan.org/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf base-files armhf 10.3+rpi1+deb10u2 [70.0 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.harukasan.org/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf ncurses-bin armhf 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 [400 kB]
Get:4 http://ftp.harukasan.org/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf ncurses-base all 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 [258 kB]
Get:5 http://ftp.harukasan.org/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libsystemd0 armhf 241-7~deb10u2+rpi1 [304 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf arandr all 0.1.9-2+rpt10 [65.6 kB]
```

sources.list

```
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

sources.list.d/raspbi.list

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
```

Comment: Please post the exact command you run and the exact message you get from `apt`.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev simple `apt upgrade` or `apt install openjdk-11-jdk` and output is normal `apt` output except it is downloading from `ftp.harukasan.org`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have provided no evidence of any problem.
I know of no way of blocking a mirror, but you can change the mirror used.

Select a mirror from https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors/

Then edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` substituting a local mirror for http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/

---

A more verbose set of instructions are in https://pimylifeup.com/raspbian-repository-mirror/ (but the end result is the same)

Comment: `ftp.harukasan.org` is too slow. Did you see `apt update` output? there is no configuration related to `ftp.harukasan.org` Therefore no way to change it.

Comment: Just follow the instructions above. Don't worry about how the mirror redirector works.

Comment: @hurelhuyag To clarify, `raspbian.raspberrypi.org` doesn't have to serve you any packages directly. It can redirect you to a mirror based on your IP address, and you have no control over which mirror is chosen. You can however, bypass the redirector entirely by hardcoding the mirror of your choice into `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev If I visit `http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org` it is seems serving packages directly. I don't how redirector works. But I solved by changing repository server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ftp.harukasan.org` is selected by the Raspbian mirror redirector (`raspbian.raspberrypi.org`, which is not a "real" mirror server).

To speed up, you can specify the nearest mirror server in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, by replacing the `raspbian.raspberrypi.org` to the nearest server's "real" address.

The nearest server could be found here:

- http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/r/raspbian-archive-keyring/raspbian-archive-keyring_20120528.2_all.deb.mirrorlist

Full list is also available here (but contains a lot of inactive servers):

- https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors

---

Unfortunately, https://ftp.harukasan.org is for domestic (South Korea) and could be very slow for overseas users. Apologise for your inconvenience.

If you want to report any issue with https://ftp.harukasan.org, please feel free to send us a mail: `harukasan-ftp@lists.launchpad.net`; or DM `@harukasan_ftp` in Twitter.

Comment: Thanks for detailed information. I didn't know about redirector. I'm user of ubuntu 10 years. But never heard this kind of feature exist. Now I know.