# What repository for Raspberry Pi 3B+ stretch? (repository is empty)

Tags: raspbian, repository

Just tried this on my RPi3B+:

```
pi@pi-boxcalmeas-01:~ $ sudo apt install samba samba-common-bin smbclient cifs-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
cifs-utils is already the newest version (2:6.7-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjs-angularjs libjs-bootstrap
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  attr libaio1 libfile-copy-recursive-perl python-dnspython python-ldb python-samba python-tdb samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools update-inetd
Suggested packages:
  python-gpgme bind9 bind9utils ctdb ldb-tools ntp | chrony smbldap-tools winbind ufw heimdal-clients
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  attr libaio1 libfile-copy-recursive-perl python-dnspython python-ldb python-samba python-tdb samba samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules
  smbclient tdb-tools update-inetd
0 upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3.580 kB/3.845 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25,0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python-samba armhf 2:4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf samba-common-bin armhf 2:4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf samba armhf 2:4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf smbclient armhf 2:4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf samba-dsdb-modules armhf 2:4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:6 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf samba-vfs-modules armhf 2:4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/python-samba_4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba-common-bin_4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba_4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/smbclient_4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba-dsdb-modules_4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/samba/samba-vfs-modules_4.5.16+dfsg-1+deb9u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

A year ago or so when I was setting this Pi up, I did not experience a problem like this.

While this link is still online: http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/ - and it lists some files and directories:

```
[DIR]   Parent Directory        -        
[ ] Contents-armhf.gz   21-Jan-2020 04:50   34M     Details
[ ] Contents-udeb-armhf.gz  12-Nov-2019 10:27   41K     Details
[DIR]   binary-armhf/   21-Jan-2020 06:03   -        
[DIR]   debian-installer/   13-Apr-2017 20:47   -        
[DIR]   source/ 21-Jan-2020 06:03   -
```

... there are no actual .deb files/packages anywhere.

Is there a new link for stretch, and if so, where do I find it?

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` before trying your upgrade?

Comment: Raspbian Stretch is out of date - why have you not re-flashed Raspbian Buster?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to diagnose the download problem has led you astray - you are looking in the wrong place.

raspbian.raspberrypi.org is slow and unreliable. This is a known problem, which affects many people (although not all) it is probably an internet routing issue.

If you keep trying it will eventually work, although (except for kernel/firmware updates) I replace in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, with a local mirror; in my case

`deb http://raspbian.melbourneitmirror.net/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi`

although you could select a local mirror from https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors/

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105824/8697