# Unable to install ANYTHING on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, apt

I have updating and all that stuff, but whenever I run sudo apt-get install..., it says errors. I am connected to the internet, and I can run update and upgrade, but I can't install. When ever I run update, it always says getting package from zerotier, which is weird since I purged it, but there is a folder left with stuff I don't know how to delete. Here is an example of me trying to install some stuff.

This is the command in running:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install netatalk screen avahi-daemon default-jdk -y
```

```bsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
avahi-daemon is already the newest version (0.7-4+b1).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  default-jdk-headless default-jre default-jre-headless libcue2 libexempi8
  libexiv2-14 libgexiv2-2 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgxps2 libiptcdata0
  libosinfo-1.0-0 libpoppler-glib8 libquvi-0.9-0.9.3 libquvi-scripts-0.9
  libtagc0 libtotem-plparser-common libtotem-plparser18
  libtracker-control-2.0-0 libtracker-miner-2.0-0 libtracker-sparql-2.0-0
  libutempter0 lua-bitop lua-expat lua-json lua-lpeg lua-socket osinfo-db
  tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs
Suggested packages:
  exiv2 libosinfo-l10n quota byobu | screenie | iselect
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-jdk default-jdk-headless default-jre default-jre-headless libcue2
  libexempi8 libexiv2-14 libgexiv2-2 libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgxps2
  libiptcdata0 libosinfo-1.0-0 libpoppler-glib8 libquvi-0.9-0.9.3
  libquvi-scripts-0.9 libtagc0 libtotem-plparser-common libtotem-plparser18
  libtracker-control-2.0-0 libtracker-miner-2.0-0 libtracker-sparql-2.0-0
  libutempter0 lua-bitop lua-expat lua-json lua-lpeg lua-socket netatalk
  osinfo-db screen tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs
0 upgraded, 34 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,212 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf lua-bitop armhf 1.0.2-5
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:2 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf lua-expat armhf 1.3.0-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:3 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf lua-lpeg armhf 1.0.0-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:4 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf lua-json all 1.3.4-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Get:5 http://raspbian.freemirror.org/raspbian buster/main armhf lua-socket armhf 3.0~rc1+git+ac3201d-4 [57.5 kB]
Err:6 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libquvi-scripts-0.9 all 0.9.20131130-1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:7 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libquvi-0.9-0.9.3 armhf 0.9.3-1.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:8 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libutempter0 armhf 1.1.6-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:9 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf screen armhf 4.6.2-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Get:10 http://raspbian.freemirror.org/raspbian buster/main armhf default-jre-headless armhf 2:1.11-71+b1 [11.1 kB]
Get:11 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf default-jre armhf 2:1.11-71+b1 [1,044 B]
Get:12 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf default-jdk-headless armhf 2:1.11-71+b1 [1,108 B]
Get:13 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf default-jdk armhf 2:1.11-71+b1 [1,060 B]
Err:14 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libcue2 armhf 2.2.1-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:15 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libexempi8 armhf 2.5.0-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:16 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libexiv2-14 armhf 0.25-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:17 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libgexiv2-2 armhf 0.10.9-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:18 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libgsf-1-common all 1.14.45-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:19 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libgsf-1-114 armhf 1.14.45-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:20 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libgxps2 armhf 0.3.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:21 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libiptcdata0 armhf 1.0.5-2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Get:22 http://raspbian.freemirror.org/raspbian buster/main armhf osinfo-db all 0.20181120-1+deb10u1 [80.8 kB]
Err:23 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libosinfo-1.0-0 armhf 1.2.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:24 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libpoppler-glib8 armhf 0.71.0-5
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:26 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libtotem-plparser-common all 3.26.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Get:25 http://raspbian.mirror.colo-serv.net/raspbian buster/main armhf libtagc0 armhf 1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.3+deb10u1 [28.0 kB]
Err:27 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libtotem-plparser18 armhf 3.26.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:28 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 armhf 2.1.8-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:29 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libtracker-control-2.0-0 armhf 2.1.8-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:30 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf libtracker-miner-2.0-0 armhf 2.1.8-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:31 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf netatalk armhf 3.1.12~ds-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:32 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf tracker armhf 2.1.8-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:33 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf tracker-extract armhf 2.1.6-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Err:34 http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf tracker-miner-fs armhf 2.1.6-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
Fetched 181 kB in 14s (12.7 kB/s)                                             
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/l/lua-bitop/lua-bitop_1.0.2-5_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/l/lua-expat/lua-expat_1.3.0-4_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/l/lua-lpeg/lua-lpeg_1.0.0-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/l/lua-json/lua-json_1.3.4-2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libq/libquvi-scripts/libquvi-scripts-0.9_0.9.20131130-1.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libq/libquvi/libquvi-0.9-0.9.3_0.9.3-1.3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libu/libutempter/libutempter0_1.1.6-3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/s/screen/screen_4.6.2-3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libc/libcue/libcue2_2.2.1-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/e/exempi/libexempi8_2.5.0-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/e/exiv2/libexiv2-14_0.25-4_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/g/gexiv2/libgexiv2-2_0.10.9-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libg/libgsf/libgsf-1-common_1.14.45-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libg/libgsf/libgsf-1-114_1.14.45-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libg/libgxps/libgxps2_0.3.1-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libi/libiptcdata/libiptcdata0_1.0.5-2.1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/libo/libosinfo/libosinfo-1.0-0_1.2.0-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/p/poppler/libpoppler-glib8_0.71.0-5_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/t/totem-pl-parser/libtotem-plparser-common_3.26.2-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/t/totem-pl-parser/libtotem-plparser18_3.26.2-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/t/tracker/libtracker-sparql-2.0-0_2.1.8-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/t/tracker/libtracker-control-2.0-0_2.1.8-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/t/tracker/libtracker-miner-2.0-0_2.1.8-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/n/netatalk/netatalk_3.1.12~ds-3_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/t/tracker/tracker_2.1.8-2_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/t/tracker-miners/tracker-extract_2.1.6-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.switch.ca/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/t/tracker-miners/tracker-miner-fs_2.1.6-1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 209.115.181.106 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Start with `sudo apt update` to get the mirror lists updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather vague and lacking detail. What does the mention of "zerotier" supposed to mean?  We don't really need hundreds of lines of error messages!

It is likely that there is a problem with the repository that has been automatically selected.

You can try manually specifying an alternate repository. See 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105824/8697

Comment: well, `mirrors.switch.ca` IP address is `209.115.181.106` - so, perhaps it is a temporary issue, or your network is screwed

Comment: I tried to connect to some websites, and my wifi works there. I also use VNC, so that means some part of the wifi is working. In the post, by zerotier, I meant the package. www.zerotier.com.