# How to increase timeout for apt update

Tags: apt

I live in the boondocks, where internet connection can be...well...let's just say "not so good."  While trying to keep my system (Buster) up to date, using 'apt update,' the reported download rates regularly vary between tens of kB/s to hundreds of B/s, to dead stop.  Not surprisingly, apt eventually gives up and terminates with "...some index files failed to download."  Also, usually, with "Undetermined Error" or "Connection timed out" followed by an IP address.

Is there a way to get apt to try again, without re-issuing the command in the terminal?

Comment: Post ACTUAL error messages! A local mirror may help (depending on actual problem) see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105824/8697

Comment: I second that a local mirror would help, especially if you have more than one device with the same OS that needs to be kept up to date!!

Answer (score 0):

This question looks like it's a better fit for Superuser, but you should be able to do

```bsh
until command
do
sleep 1
done
```

which will repeat `command` until it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file ex. `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99timeouts`

Add the rows:

```
Acquire::http::timeout "240";
Acquire::https::timeout "240";
```

where "240" is a timeout in seconds.