`sudo apt update` is so slow that it times out
I just installed Raspberry Pi OS Lite (32-bit) for my Raspberry Pi 1B and SSHed into it from my PC. I would like to get lighttpd installed, but to do that I need to update apt first. When I run sudo apt update here's my output:
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm InRelease [15.0 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease [39.0 kB]
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [14.5 MB]
Ign:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease [39.0 kB]
Ign:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [14.5 MB]
Ign:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease [39.0 kB]
Ign:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages [506 kB]
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [14.5 MB]
Ign:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages [477 kB]
Ign:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [14.5 MB]
Ign:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages [506 kB]
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
  Connection timed out [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [20.0 MB]
Ign:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages [477 kB]
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
  Connection timed out [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
  Connection timed out [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Ign:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages [506 kB]
Ign:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages [477 kB]
Ign:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages [506 kB]
Ign:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages [477 kB]
Ign:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages [1,978 kB]
Err:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main armhf Packages
  Connection timed out [IP: 176.126.240.84 80]
Get:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages [1,874 kB]
Err:5 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm/main arm64 Packages

Fetched 22.5 kB in 6min 8s (61 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian/dists/bookworm/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection timed out [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection timed out [IP: 176.126.240.84 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-arm64/Packages
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

How can I update apt without it timing out?
What I've tried
I have checked my internet speed as described in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/269821 and it seems fine.
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by 31173 Services AB (London) [1462.18 km]: 57.692 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 31.33 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 26.93 Mbit/s

I also checked my read/write speeds to the SD card using dd, and it looks ok:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dd if=/dev/zero of=./TestingFile bs=100M count=10 oflag=direct
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 65.7005 s, 16.0 MB/s
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dd if=./TestingFile of=/dev/zero bs=100M count=10 oflag=dsync
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB, 1000 MiB) copied, 45.0119 s, 23.3 MB/s

I checked htop while running sudo apt update and htop is what uses the most resources during the update process (sudo apt update uses very little resources).

I have also tried changing the apt sources list to two separate sources, but that did not help.
I also tried increasing the timeout limit to 1800 seconds by following this stack overflow post: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/144567, but then the update freezes while updating the third URL, like this:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease [39.0 kB]
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm InRelease [15.0 kB]
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [14.5 MB]
0% [3 Packages 141 kB/14.5 MB 1%] [1 InRelease 17.2 kB/39.0 kB 44%]

I also tried disabling IPv6 by following this article, but to no avail: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-the-slow-apt-get-update-issue-on-linux-machines/
Finally I re-imaged the SD-card, but this too did not work.
Edit:
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm InRelease [15.0 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [14.5 MB]
Ign:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:4 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/contrib armhf Packages [62.3 kB]
Get:5 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/non-free armhf Packages [118 kB]
Get:6 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/rpi armhf Packages [1,360 B]
Get:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [14.5 MB]
Ign:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [14.5 MB]
Ign:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Get:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [14.5 MB]
Err:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
  Connection timed out [IP: 193.35.52.51 80]
Get:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages [20.0 MB]
Err:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
  Connection timed out [IP: 193.35.52.51 80]
Err:3 http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
  Connection timed out [IP: 193.35.52.51 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian/dists/bookworm/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection timed out [IP: 193.35.52.51 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I tried wgeting the URL that failed and got a 404. Maybe the mirror is broken?
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wget http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-armhf/Packages
--2024-09-21 20:23:51--  http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-armhf/Packages
Resolving raspbian.trivini.no (raspbian.trivini.no)... 193.35.52.51, 2001:67c:29f4::51
Connecting to raspbian.trivini.no (raspbian.trivini.no)|193.35.52.51|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2024-09-21 20:23:51 ERROR 404: Not Found.

The /etc/apt/sources.list file looks like this:
deb [ arch=armhf ] http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian bookworm main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian/ bookworm main contrib non-free rpi

Edit 2:
I've tried these mirrors:

http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian
http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/raspbian/raspbian
http://mirror.terrahost.no/linux/raspbian/raspbian/
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian
http://raspbian.mirror.triple-it.nl/raspbian/

and they all fail on the same URL: http://raspbian.mirror.triple-it.nl/raspbian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-armhf/Packages
Edit 3:
I tried editing my /etc/apt/sources.list as @goldilocks suggested, but then I get a different error:
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [55.4 kB]
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [55.4 kB]
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
  Connection timed out [IP: 151.101.86.132 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bookworm-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $

Edit 4
GPG key directory
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1183 Jul  4 02:05 raspberrypi-archive-stable.gpg


the issue isn't with apt update being slow, it's the response from the server that is either slow, or never comes

@JaromandaX That does make sense, but at the same time I've tested my internet connection and I have tested 3 separate servers from different countries in Europe. Are the packages simply broken? Is there any other way of installing packages then? Now, when I try installing lighttpd, I get the error: E: Package 'lighttpd' has no installation candidate, so I'm guessing I need one of those sources that are failing...

yes, lighttpd is available as far as I can ascertain (haven't used 32bit raspberry pi's in many years now)

This is unusual. I've never seen this before. One odd thing in your output: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring...??? If you've got another PC/Mac, you might try opening a browser, and entering the URLs that Failed to fetch; FOR EXAMPLE: http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-armhf/Packages. I've loaded them in my browser window, and they (at least the lists) seem to fetch just fine. Perhaps this is a temporal issue?

@Seamus Thank you for the suggestions. I will try again another day and also check the link on another computer.

@Seamus Does this give any more information?
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wget http://193.35.52.51
--2024-09-21 13:08:36--  http://193.35.52.51/
Connecting to 193.35.52.51:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://193.35.52.51/ [following]
--2024-09-21 13:08:36--  https://193.35.52.51/
Connecting to 193.35.52.51:443... connected.
The certificate's owner does not match hostname ‘193.35.52.51’

Not sure...  where did you get that IP address?  It's not listed in your question.

@Seamus The IP address is from one of the IP addresses that were listed next to the connection timed out messages. The IP address is different from the one in my OP because I changed the source for apt to a different one.

You cannot change your sources arbitrarily.

@Seamus I changed the URL in /etc/apt/sources.list to a different mirror for raspberry pi apt http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian (found from https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors). Maybe that I changed my "sources" was not the right terminology?
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Connection timed out [IP: 193.35.52.51 80]

I tried wgeting the URL that failed to fetch and not the IP address (it doesn't make sense to get the IP-address directly I realize now...) and I got a 404. So maybe the mirror is broken? http://raspbian.trivini.no/raspbian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-armhf/Packages

Resolving raspbian.trivini.no (raspbian.trivini.no)... 193.35.52.51, 2001:67c:29f4::51
Connecting to raspbian.trivini.no (raspbian.trivini.no)|193.35.52.51|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2024-09-21 20:19:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.

@Seamus I edited the OP, it's a bit easier to read there

Is this: https://downloads.raspberrypi.com/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2024-07-04/ the image you downloaded?  Did you install it with the Raspberry Pi Imager?

Please try @goldilocks answer. I think I agree with him - you may have inadvertently bodged your source lists. N.B. there are two source lists: 1) /etc/apt/sources.list and  2) /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list.

Thank you so much, I'll try this right away. I installed it through the Raspberry Pi Imager

When you re-installed, what image did you start from? If it wasn't bookworm to start with, you can't reliably upgrade Rpi OS this way. Edit in the output from ls -l /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d (that's where those pubic keys should be).

@goldilocks I ran this command, suggested by ChatGPT  and now it works!
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 54404762BBB6E853 BDE6D2B9216EC7A8 0E98404D386FA1D9 6ED0E7B82643E131

I still get the warning errors from GPG though, so I'll edit them in, if they may be relevant. Thank you for the help!

Ah: https://askubuntu.com/q/1525967  Anyway, hopefully all's well that ends well.  I'm going to close this as I don't think it is going to be all that useful to posterity.

"I still get the warning errors from GPG though" -> You're better off pursing this kind of stuff on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

@goldilocks Ok, again thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate it.

You need to rule out the possibility that your (perhaps pointless) modifications to the sources lists are causing the problem.
Edit /etc/apt/sources.list so it contains only this (uncommented) line:
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bookworm main contrib non-free rpi

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ should contain one file (raspi.list) with one uncommented line:
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian/ bookworm main

Now run apt update.  WRT installing lighthttpd:

I would like to get lighttpd installed, but to do that I need to update apt first.

It's not mandatory, you should still be able to install it.  Also, the errors you posted are not completely fatal, and you should still be able to install after that (unless: XY problem).

The debian sources are only for 64bit OS which obviously won't work for Pi model B which requires ARM6

Okay -- that explains why the keys weren't in that image; I did check a virgin one but it was for 64-bit (I thought in passing that it should include the 32-bit archives as well since that stuff could be installed).  The only 32-bit install I have is bullseye and has been fiddled with a fair bit, but I've edited the above based on that.
